# Detect if response was received by the remote client

Tags: flask

In the flask application I'm currently building, it is critical to know if the client received the response sent by the server.
The client is on a mobile connection and can, theoretically, disappear at any time.

Expecting the client to send another request confirming that it received a response to the first one would raise similar problems.

---

Since the communication occurs over TCP, the server should be able to detect if the response was received.

Looking through the documentation, I've found that the Werkzeug library has a [ClientDisconnected](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected) exception, but adding an flask error_handler for that exception doesn't seem to do anything.

Is this exception silenced by flask? Does he expose an API with similar functionality?

Comment: Looks like it IS silenced by default:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/0.10.4/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L180-L181

Comment: What i thought that comment meant was that it is there to "hide" some other exception (in the underlying socket library, i guess?).
But I only found usages of this exception on the [LimitedStream](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/d4e8b3f46c51e7374388791282e66323f64b3068/werkzeug/wsgi.py#L962-L969) class, and no reference to this exception in the flask repository.


The documentation also points that this exception is unreliable, so maybe I shouldn't be going in this direction anyway...

Comment: HTTP isn't designed for you to care if the client actually received the response. You will need to use Web sockets for this. Remember you TCP connection is not necersarily direct to the client but may be to a proxy, webserver, or anything else for that matter.